# Mount only specific partition without sudo password?

Tags: usb, mount, nautilus, drive

I want to create a custom live usb stick with two partitions: one for the OS and one data partition.

Now the users should only be able to mount said data partition (which should be mounted automatically), **but** neither any internal drives nor another usb or network drive.

I thought it would be easier to find a solution, but I couldn't find someone with a similar problem. Can somemone help me out?

Kind regards!

Comment: Make an entry in fstab by UUID and use the user or users option

Comment: I think the problem is that I won't know the UUID before I apply the image to all usb drives

Comment: Mount by lable then and set a label when you make the partition